Does a 24V LiFePo4 Battery Bank Save Physical Space Over 12V
If I have a set volume of space - say the battery compartment on an RV - and I'm trying to fit the most amount of electrical energy in that space in LiFePo4 batteries, do I have an advantage in using a higher voltage level (48V versus 24V versus 12V) or is the energy density of LiFePo4 batteries fairly fixed and it's just a matter of arranging sells in series-parallel to get different levels for delivery of that energy over the wire?
I understand that if I have a bunch of 12V batteries, I have to have more wires, connectors, busbars, etc. but I'm trying to disregard that and just focus on the physical volume of the batteries themselves.
In one example scenario, I have a 24V 200Ah battery with physical dimensions of L20.47W10.59H8.66 inch = 1877 in^3. That battery has 5120Wh of energy in it, so I'm using 5120/1877 to get 2.7 W/in^3 of energy density. Here's the product in this scenario.
In another scenario, I have 4 12V 100Ah batteries connected in series parallel (2S2P). Those batteries have physical dimensions of L13W6.77H8.43 inch = 742 in^3 * 4 = 2968 in^3. They have 1280Wh of energy each (totally 5120Wh... same as the first scenario) for an energy density of 5120/2968 to get 1.7 W/in^3 of energy density. Here's the product in this scenario.
So, it seems that the 24V bank has more energy density, but that goes against my intuition that the lithium cells (in roughly equivalent batteries) are all the same and voltage levels are just a matter of series-parallel arrangements.
What am I missing?

Within manufacturing tolerances, one cell of a given design is going to store the same energy as the next. The manufacturer will promise somewhat less than that, if they're honest.
Cells that can deliver more power tend to have lower energy density.
If you have two batteries that are stuffed with the same number of the same design cells, with no leftover space, then they should store the same energy, even if they're wired to deliver different voltages.
The difference you see is probably packaging efficiency. If the power levels are different, that could account for some of what you're seeing.  If the batteries are different brands or models, different cell manufacturers and possibly different levels of care about longevity could also be in play.

I think you may be right, Tim, that it comes down to packaging efficiency. As Jasen mentioned in another comment, the 12V 400Ah battery from the same company is the same size and price as the 24V 200Ah battery. It's when you try to get the same energy using 4 different boxes that you start losing space. I just didn't realize how significant it was. I'd like to do the same comparison on weight, because I bet it's less dramatic. The plastic is pretty light and I see a lot of air in some of these boxes when I see people take them apart on YouTube. Thanks for the help!

If the company is using standard automotive battery sizes that'll just make things worse -- it's not like a standard-size cell is a liquid that can just be poured into a case to completely fill it.  So a smaller case will be more likely to not pack efficiently.

No, 12V is actually the same size (same price too)
https://www.litime.com/products/12v-400ah-lifepo4-lithium-battery
Having 4 separate batteries instead of one is what wastes space.

A given battery chemistry has a particular value of "energy density", regardless of how you configure it for voltage vs. current.
So no, the size won't be significantly affected whichever way you go. But if you choose higher voltage and lower current, wiring in general will be less bulky.
The differences in your calculations are due to the significant volume occupied by the plastic cases of the batteries in question.

That's what my intuition says, but can you tell me why my scenarios above seem to contradict that?

You're adding together the volume taken up by the physical containers or packaging of the separate batteries, something the monolithic battery does not have.

High current cells tend to lower energy density. Cheap cells tend to over promise on capacity.  In model airplane applications I see up to 20% difference in promised capacity for same-weight cells coming from premium vs. cheapo sources.

No sir. Battery volumetric energy is called energy density and is measured in Wh/L. When comparing a single battery chemistry, it does not matter if the battery is configured as 12 volts at 100 AH or 24 volts at 50 AH; both batteries are equal in capacity (1200 Wh), volume, and weight.
However, higher high-voltage systems are more efficient, safer, and less expensive to install and operate. For example, if you have a 1000-watt load and you use a 12-volt system, you will require a much larger, expensive copper wire. There is a reason utilities use high voltage.
I have an off-grid solar system, and I would never consider a 12—or 24-volt system with 5000-watt panels and a 2000-watt inverter. I run 48 volts and am looking to go even higher. Always select the highest voltage available.
Consider this scenario: You purchase two 12-volt, 100 AH batteries from a store. You can connect them in series to achieve 24 volts at 100 AH, or in parallel to obtain 12 volts at 200 AH. Both configurations give you 2400 Wh capacity in the same 1-pound box.

Thanks, Dereck. Yeah, I'm familiar with the tradeoffs of voltage and current and the many advantages of raising the voltage. I was just wondering why it seems the four 12V batteries in my scenario that equal the 24V in terms of energy took up so much volume.

The more series cells you add, the greater chance of mismatch where the weakest cell dies first with a rapid dis/over-charge while the entire battery charge transfer is incomplete.  Initially, cells are matched by the factory process control but variations in machines or chemistry batches of lead batches lead to the possibility of a 0.1 to 1% mismatch.  The analogy is getting 10% supercaps or any large 10% e-caps to match from different batches.  If one gets parts from the same batch they may be within 2% of the 10% range. I doubt batteries are any better in tolerance of rated Wh or ESR specs than Supercaps or large e-caps.
For batteries, it is more critical if the user depletes to 100% DoD and then charges to 100% SOC and worse yet on rapid charge. That accelerates cell death or reduces the number of recharge cycles. The more conservative one uses batteries, the longer lifespan and total life they will produce.
Thus, IMHO, for the same supplier and design, it is best to get the battery pack produced by the factory in the same unit so they take care to match tight specs. Rising ESR accelerates temperature rise, which accelerates C degradation and reduces MTBF, generally 50% for every 10'C rise in plate temperature.
For these reasons, this is my recommendation.
https://www.litime.com/products/48v-100ah-lithium-home-storage-battery
Although the 100A continuous rating is not as good as the 200A rating which suggests a higher ESR spec or they may be just being more conservative.
Batteries of the same Lithium technology are often judged by the highest weight so you want the lowest density solution for the best heavy-duty plates.
But we are blind to the ESR specs and internal temperature rise when the 200A BMS are dissipating power so a lot of guesswork demands better life test results.  The mfg ought to make this available to serious customers.


Complementary to other comments and answers:
I'm largely but not completely "making this up" as I go, but consider each point has some merit. Factors work both ways.
Overall I'd have expected to have disproved the effect that you have observed :-) :-( . While observation beats expectation, an examination of the following factors may still be useful.
_________________
Factors leading to multiple batteries having increased area.:
When using smaller batteries in a physical array the smaller batteries will have additional "walls" in each direction.
eg a 2x2 array has 4 walls in each direction rather than 2.
A 4 x 1 array has 8 walls rather than 2. This leads to added dead area.
(I started to produce some simple equations to show area change for ega 2x2 array with walls of say 10% of width but decided not to - to many incertainties but inspection of a few batteries would show how importantthis factor was.)

Factors leading to a single battery having increased area.:
A larger battery has N x the mass and must be strong enough to tolerate the additional forces. For a battery deposited on an edge with modest speed a large battery has more mass per side length and greater thickness is probably in order.
LiFePO4 cells and batteries MUST be tension strapped to prevent substantial change in dimension during charge/discharge cycles. Failure to do this leads to reduced of much reduced battery life. A larger battery will (non calculated intuition based claim :-) ) have more stresses due to mass and forces fromm charge cycling and need thicker materials (given the same material properties).  In addition to the electrically induced cycling stresses one would like to avoid stresses brought about by case flexure. This should be minimal when mounted but could be significant during handling.
As a very general and far from universal 'rule' I'd expect that larger batteries which necessarily cost more will be more likely to be built to a better quality standard. How much better will vary with manufacturer.
